# html(); overriding within if and else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having an issue with  `html();` content overriding in my plugin. The issue is it does not not return null (blank) based on the conditions

The logic of the plugin is it replaces all elements in a `<span>` by subtracting a percentage off the span value. The plugin changes the text within the `<span>` based on the following conditions:

1. If threshold is greater than 899.
2. If a data-atrribute does not equal the array:

Essentially I want to display the sale tag based on the conditions that are set, however the sale tag is always showing, regardless of the coniditons.

Here is the plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.TTprices = function(options){

    // Default Settings
        //
        var settings = $.extend({
        threshold : 899,
            discount    :   40,
      exclude : ['xxx', 'xdd']
        }, options);

        return this.each(function() {

      var $this = $(this);
      var $value = $this.contents()[0].textContent;
      var $price = parseFloat($value);
      var $discount = "." + (settings.discount);
      var $total = $price - ($price * $discount);
      var $productID = $this.data('product-id');
      var $exclude = (settings.exclude);

      var $saleTag =  $("span[data-badge='priceline']"); // Sale Tag



        $this.html(function(){ 
          if ($.inArray($productID, $exclude) !== -1)  {
               $saleTag.html(); // Sale tag off
               return $this.html();
          } 
          else if ($value != (settings.threshold)) {
                $saleTag.html(settings.discount + '% OFF'); // Sale tag on
              return $this.html().replace($value, $total.toFixed(2)+" ");
          } 
          else {
              $saleTag.html(); // Sale tag off
              return $this.html();
          } 
      });

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

HTML:

```
<span class="price" data-product-id="xkk">1999 <span class="currency">KR</span>
  <span class="sale" data-badge="priceline"></span>
</span><br>
<span class="price" data-product-id="xxx">3999 <span class="currency">KR</span>
  <span class="sale" data-badge="priceline"></span>
</span><br>
<span class="price" data-product-id="ccc">2499 <span class="currency">KR</span>
  <span class="sale" data-badge="priceline"></span>
</span><br>
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/panoply/hQqtU/422/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not seleting properly the `$saleTag` element. The code you use is:

```
var $saleTag =  $("span[data-badge='priceline']"); // Sale Tag
```

which selects all the `span` tags which have the data-bagde attribute equal to priceline.

The correct code should be:

```
var $saleTag =  $this.find("span[data-badge='priceline']"); // Sale Tag
```

which selects the `span` tag which is inside the current `.price` element in the `each()` loop.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/hQqtU/427/.

Comment: To add to that, `$saleTag.html()` doesn't empty the HTML, it simply returns the current HTML (which they already seem to have demonstrated): http://jsfiddle.net/hQqtU/426/ -- OP can use `.html('')` or `.empty()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, this works! –  Would you recommend a better way to integrate this logic?

Comment: Maybe you can insert the `$saleTag` dynamically, only when is needed. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hQqtU/429/.